# VMware: Shared folders on mac not updated on the virtual machine

Tags: vmware, unix

I'm using vmware on mac to emulate Ubuntu.

When I change shared folders files on OSX I don't see the changes (automatically updated) in Ubuntu...

When I added the folder, everything was visible and it perfectly worked, but when I edited some files, these become red in the Ubuntu terminal, and I cannot see the new versions of them (even if I restart Ubuntu, I guess the only way is to remove and add the shared folder again).

Any help ?

Comment: WHat version of VMware Fusion? You did make sure the VMware tools are installed and up to date, correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've solved. The problem was that I was using symbolic links applied to the files instead of the parent folder.