# VMWare Shared Folders empty on macOS virtual machine from macOS host

Tags: big-sur, vmware

I'm trying to share the macOS Big Sur host's **Downloads** folder with a virtual machine that's also on Big Sur. As you can see from the screen grab below, **Enable Shared Folders** is checked, the **Downloads** folder is checked, and yet the **VMware Shared Folders** folder is empty (and **Open in Guest…** is disabled, if that's relevant). The shared folder is the actual **Downloads** folder and not an alias. This appears to be the same issue brought up on VMware's forums without resolution [here](https://communities.vmware.com/t5/VMware-Fusion-Discussions/Shared-folders-between-Mac-OS-host-and-Mac-OS-VM/td-p/2887949). [This post](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/3646/vmware-shared-folders-on-mac-not-updated-on-the-virtual-machine) was also similar but didn't help me to figure it out.

[image]

How can I access the files in the shared folder in the virtual machine?

Comment: Can you confirm there are are no aliases, symlinks, etc. involved. Can you share other folders?

Comment: Make sure that VMware Fusion is allowed to access the Downloads folder in System Preferences > Security & Privacy > Privacy > Files and Folders.

Comment: No alias, etc., involved. The folder in question is the actual Downloads folder. Edited the question to clarify that point.

Comment: I don't seem to be able to add new apps to Privacy > Files and Folders; the + button is disabled even when unlocked. But VMware is definitely not in that list, so that may be the issue.